# How can I get my API key if the API doesn't have a login as requirement

Tags: javascript, json, api, api-key

## Here is the API documentation

### **Base URL**

[https:...../api/)

### **Endpoints**

**/games/**

Allowed actions:

- POST to create a new game

Mandatory parameters for POST action:

- name: name of the game

Parameters example for POST action (sent in the body of the request in JSON format):

```json
{ 
    "name": "My cool new game" 
}
```

Return value: unique identifier for the game

```json
{
    "result": "Game with ID: **Zl4d7IVkemOTTVg2fUdz** added."
}
```

**/games/:id/scores/**

URL parameters:

- id: unique identifier of the game

URL example: `/games/Zl4d7IVkemOTTVg2fUdz/scores/`

Allowed actions:

- POST to create a new score for the given game
- GET to get a list of scores for the given game

Mandatory parameters for POST action:

- user: name of the user
- score: points (number)

Parameters example for POST action (sent in the body of the request in JSON format):

```json
{ 
    "user": "John Doe",
    "score": 42
}
```

Return value for POST action:

```json
{
    "result": "Leaderboard score created correctly."
}
```

Parameters for GET action: none

Return value for GET action:

```json
{
    "result": [
        {
            "user": "John Doe",
            "score": 42
        },
        {
            "user": "Peter Parker",
            "score": 35
        },
        {
            "user": "Wonder Woman",
            "score": 50
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is: how can I get my KEY once I don't need to sign in?

Comment: Where in the API is it describing the need for a key? Can you link to their actual documentation?

Comment: I think you need to share the URL of the website where you found this api before anyone can help out.

Answer (score 0):

just like some open API's you need to register and get this api key to prove you identity. Like Open Weather Map, is free to use and no login (for the user) to check the info. But as a developer you might have to register an account to get this API key.

It's just for not flooding their API with bots or other malicious stuff.

Comment: yes but in this case, there is no way to register it's just this documentation and nothing else, so again: how can I get my KEY WITHOUT register?

Comment: @brugobi share the api please, let me check it!

Comment: that's what I posted here the whole documentation nothing else but that

Comment: I found the answer I tried to post here but I couldn't because of the format

Comment: Interesting, can't you change the format?! I am very curious about the solution...